# SpringBootAdmin App cannot able to Login

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-admin

I am using springbootadmin module to monitor some Spring Boot applications. I have used the springbootadmin module as a WAR deployed in Tomcat.

When I open the application from http://localhost:8080/springbootadmin/login.html it opens the login page and after I enter the username and password, the page is redirecting to http://localhost:8080/login which returns a 404 page. I expect it to show the springbootadmin dashboard instead.

Please find my properties file details:

```
spring.application.name=spring-boot-admin-server

security.user.name=admin
security.user.password=admin

spring.boot.admin.url=http://localhost:8081/admin

spring.boot.admin.client.service-url=http://localhost:8081/admin

spring.boot.admin.client.username=${security.user.name}

spring.boot.admin.client.password=${security.user.password}
```

Comment: are you using spring boot admin as a spring boot admin application??

Comment: I am using springbootadmin application as a war.

Comment: I would want to set it as a spring boot application itself. Hmm.. Any specific reason?

Comment: Issue solved by adding spring.profiles.active=secure. Since In java code, I have two profile.

Comment: Okay... Please mark it closed then.